# Read 2 JSON Request from iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

on the php side i wrote the following code:

```
 ......
 sendResponse(200, json_encode($result1));
 sendResponse(200, json_encode($result2));
```

Now on the Xcode side i Wrote the Following code:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSArray *carsType = [responseDict allValues];
    if (carsType != Nil) {
        self.carsTypeArray = carsType;
        [carsTypeTableView reloadData];


    }
 }
```

the problem is if i comment one of the php codes, the obj-c code work 100%. but i need to know how to read the 2 JSON Respond.

Any idea Please.

Comment: What does `sendResponse` do?  Are you really trying to send two HTTP responses without receiving two HTTP requests?

Comment: @JeremyP I receiving one HTTP request but i need to send two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$result[] = $result1;
$result[] = $result2;
sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
```

`[responseDict objectAtIndex:0]` will be `$result1`.

`[responseDict objectAtIndex:1]` will be `$result2`.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, HTTP requires one response to each request.  You can't send two hTTP response messages in a row and expect the client to understand.

The easiest way to send two pieces of JSON in one HTTP response is to wrap them in a JSON array e.g.

```
[ { "foo" : "bar" }, { "foo" : "baz" }]
```

I imagine in PHP if you stick result1 and result2 into a PHP array and JSON encode it, you'd get the right JSON string.

On the iPhone, when you send `-JSONValue` to the response, you'll get a `NSArray` returned containing your two JSON objects.